# How to send repetive numbers to a new blank sheet from VB code

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have a question is it possible to write a code from VB excel, and from the code send repetitive numbers to a column for example 1 to repeat 9 times and 2 9 times and 3 9 times in the same column repetitive 9 times for each  number up to 66. if is possible could you please give me a code example. I am new in vb excel

```
Dim Target As Worksheet
Dim x As Long
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Display")
'Write "I will not chew gum in class" 100 times
  For x = 1 To 100
    Debug.Print x & ". 9."
  Next x
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. No, we will not write the code for you. This is not a "code for free" site, it is where coders come for help on bugs/issues in their own code. What have you tried? Do you have any code you can share? Try to write something first, and if you cannot figure it out then check with us. See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: Hello yes I have some code I have been working on I will add here shortly, thanks for the response.

Comment: Hello I added part of the code I worked on any better suggestions? thanks.

Comment: If you want to print something out to an excel sheet, you will not use `Debug.Print`. Just locate the cell you want to put data into and give it a value: `Sheets("Display").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hello World!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path.  As mentioned, you don't want to use `Debug.Print`, but instead set the values to the cells:

```
Sub t()
Dim numStart As Long, numEnd As Long, i As Long, nextRow As Long
numStart = 1
numEnd = 66
nextRow = 1

With Worksheets("Display")
    For i = numStart To numEnd    ' From column A to I (1 to 9)
        .Range(.Cells(nextRow, 1), .Cells(nextRow + 8, 1)).Value = i
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks good thanks, I might need to add more stuff to my report I will keep working on it and let you know if I need more help. thanks again.

Comment: @AndresBryan29 - if this works for your question, would you mind checking as the "Answer"?